# Snowflake output when run in Fargate

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

Is it possible to see the output of a Snowflake SQL statement when the SQL is run in Fargate? For example, if the SQL was just: SELECT CURRENT_DATE;

I was hoping the output would appear in a CloudWatch log, but it doesn't.

Comment: if the output of the select prints to stdout than it should be in the CW logs (if configured). Do you see other logs (but not the output of the select) or you just don't see the logs at all?

Comment: I can find logs, but they do not contain output.

Comment: Logs intercept everything that is printed to stdout. I can only thing that the query you are alluding to does not output to stdout.